# Monitoring sim based POS terminals

Tags: gprs

Is there a way one can monitor sim card based mobile data terminal remotely  The terminal is a POS device which connects to a server via GPRS.

regards, 
Brian

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Long answer: Tell us what have you tried and where are you stuck. This is too broad to answer

Comment: Hi Pavel, I tried pinging the device but I noticed that the IP changes dynamically when the device connects via GPRS.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I am going to ditch into my personal knowledge: I was working for T-Mobile Czech Republic during years 2006 - 2007 as tech support, also supporting customers to have POS terminals working and accessible.

There are two ways how to help you:

1) Static IP adress: I dont know, if it is still in offer, ask your mobile provider. But basically you can get static IP adress (pingable) or semi-static IP (pingable, but can change every time device reconnects to GPRS). It will require restart of the device and you will certainly pay some monthly fee for this.

2) M2M data tariff: You can program your device to constantly send its status somewhere, but in normal GPRS tariff it would cost you loads of money. M2M data tariffs are made for devices which send loads of small requests over time.

TL;DR: Call your data provider. There will be people willing to help you. Including the setup.